# Como utilizar misma Funcion JS en diferentes Dropdownlist

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función javascript que utilizo para recoger el precio según el producto seleccionado, pero solamente lo hace en un dropdownlist, y en mi tabla genero varios de estos mismo según los que desee el usuario, como podría implementar la misma función en los distintos Dropdownlist creados.

JavaScript:

```
$("#id_detallepedido_set-0-producto").change(function () {
    producto_id = $(this).val();
    var url = '/control/price/'+producto_id;

    $.ajax({              
    type: "GET",    
    url: url,                   
    data: {
        'producto': producto_id 
    },
    success: function (data) {   
        console.log('Funciono!');
        console.log(data);
        $("#id_detallepedido_set-0-precio").val(data);       
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert('error' + data);
        //console.log(data);
    } 

    });        

});
```

Donde "id_detallepedido_set-0-producto" es el id del primer dropdownlist creado automaticamente, y "id_detallepedido_set-0-precio" es el id del Field al que le paso el Precio, el cual tambien es creado automaticamente.

Estoy utilizando Django para crear estos dropdownlists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución:
Agregar una clase a cada dropdown y aplicar Onchange function en dicha clase.

```
$(document).on("change", ".mydropdownclass" , function() {
    producto_id = $(this).val();
    var url = '/control/price/'+producto_id;
    //console.log(producto_id);

    //Consiguiendo el Field Precio buscandolo con su class name
    field = $(this).closest("tr").find('.mypricefield').attr('id');
    console.log(field);

    $.ajax({              
    type: "GET",    
    url: url,                   
    data: {
        'producto': producto_id 
    },
    success: function (data) {   
        //console.log('Funciono!');
        console.log("Price: " + data);
        $("#" + field).val(data);
        CalcularTotal ();      
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert('Ha ocurrido un error, intentalo de nuevo');
        //console.log(data);
        CalcularTotal ();
    } 

    });        

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Podría aplicar el evento sobre una clase que tenga todos los dropdown y utilizar el id para actualizar el valor después de obtener la respuesta. Algo similar a:

```
    $(".dropdown-class").change(function () {
        var dropdownId = $(this).attr("id");
        producto_id = $(this).val();
        var url = '/control/price/'+producto_id;

        $.ajax({              
        type: "GET",    
        url: url,                   
        data: {
            'producto': producto_id 
        },
        success: function (data) {   
            console.log('Funciono!');
            console.log(data);
            $(dropdownId).val(data);       
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert('error' + data);
            //console.log(data);
        } 

        });        

    });
```

Comment: La clase podria ser de un div? y debe de llevar el . antes del nombre de la clase?

Comment: La clase debe estar al mismo nivel del _id_ del dropdown (Lleva punto `.` antes ya que se refiere a una clase). Ejemplo `<div class='dropdown-class' id='id_detallepedido_set-0-precio'>`

Comment: Pero en este caso los dropdownlist se generan a traves de un form de django: https://imgur.com/a/J5DNC7p